# Regex for two words

Tags: python, regex

I'm not able to create a regex for capture two separate words.
For example the pattern must contain the word (pizza)+ and (cheese|tomatoes)* like this:

I want eat a pizza with cheese

capture:

```
pizza, cheese
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What language are you using? Different languages often have different (albeit similar) syntax for handling regexes.

Comment: I use python for the example

Comment: You can use `(pizza|cheese|tomatoes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). It will return all matched strings.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b(pizza|cheese|tomatoes)\b', 'I want eat a pizza with cheese')
['pizza', 'cheese']
```